# Detect when layout is loaded in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How could I detect this using also a `StatelessWidget`?

I found this https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout#-readme-tab- but it needs to be a `StateFulWidget`

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? A `Stateless` widget, as the name indicates, has no state and none of the methods a `Statefull` widget has. It's more of just layout design, almost like html for web.

Comment: I just need to know when the layout is loaded on the app. I want to display some ads but if I do it before it hasn't finished yet the performance is not that good so I need to wait

Comment: Why can't you use a Statefull widget then, and trigger your ads on `initState`?

Comment: All my widget are `Stateles` widget since I use a global provider. Even if use a `Stateful` one I'd have to use that package as well because `initState` is not exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your performance problem then.

Comment: well, that's more difficult to explain. I have some other widgets working there. 
The thing is that, I'd like to know if it's possible to check on a Stateles widget when the layout is completely loaded on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, the `Stateless` Widget does not have any methods or properties that you can use to check if it's finished building. You can only do this with `Stateful` widgets. Check the documentation of the [Stateless](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) Widget yourself to verify this information.

Comment: is there any possible way to archive this using `StateFulBuilder` with `StatelesWidget`?